# Replacing default admin display for adding Foreign Key for Page

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm looking for a way to replace default display for Page Foreign Key in admin.
Django cms is reading all pages and titles for pages and it's putting it in a select html tag. My problem is that I have more than 10000 pages and generating that list takes some time. The plugin I wrote can have multiple of links like that and Django cms is loading that list for every element, so time is multiplied by number of elements. I would love to have a way to just press a button for a new window to show up where user can select page from a list in that new window and simply add it to an element in a plugin. I tried to use django-autocomplete-light but I can't get it to work with cms.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) does.